# Sliding window aggregate for year-week in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

My question is about sliding window sum up in bigquery.

I have a table like the following

```
run_id      year_week     value
  001        201451         5
  001        201452         8
  001        201501         1
  001        201505         5
  003        201352         8
  003        201401         1
  003        201405         5
```

Here for each year the week can range from 01 to 53. For example year 2014 has last week which is 201452 but year 2015 has last week which is 201553. If it makes life easier I only have 5 years, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 and 2017 and only year 2015 has weeks those go upto 53.

Now for each run I am trying to get a sliding window sum of the values. Each  `year_week` would assume the sum of the values next 5 `year_week` (including itself) for the current run_id (e.g. `001`). For example the following could be a an output from the current table

```
run_id    year_week   aggregate_sum
  001      201451      5+8+1+0+0
  001      201452      8+1+0+0+0
  001      201501      1+0+0+0+5
  001      201502      0+0+0+5+0
  001      201503      0+0+5+0+0
  001      201504      0+5+0+0+0
  001      201505      5+0+0+0+0
  003      201352      8+1+0+0+0
  003      201401      1+0+0+0+5
  003      201402      0+0+0+5+0
  003      201403      0+0+5+0+0
  003      201404      0+5+0+0+0
  003      201405      5+0+0+0+0
```

To explain what is happening, the next 5 weeks for 201451 including itself would be 201451,201452,201501,201502,201503 . If there is a value for those weeks in the table for current `run_id` we just sum them up which would be, 5+8+1+0+0, because the corresponding value for a `year_week` is 0 if it is not in the table.

Is it possible to do it using sliding window operation in bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH weeks AS (
  SELECT 100* year + week year_week
  FROM UNNEST([2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]) year, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, IF(EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE(1+year,1,1)) = 1, 52, 53))) week
), temp AS (
  SELECT i.run_id, w.year_week, d.year_week week2, value
  FROM  weeks w 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT run_id FROM `project.dataset.table`) i
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` d
  USING(year_week, run_id)
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT run_id, year_week, 
    SUM(value) OVER(win) aggregate_sum
  FROM temp
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY run_id ORDER BY year_week ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT row AND 4 FOLLOWING
  )
)
WHERE NOT aggregate_sum IS NULL
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '001' run_id, 201451 year_week, 5 value UNION ALL
  SELECT '001', 201452, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT '001', 201501, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '001', 201505, 5 
), weeks AS (
  SELECT 100* year + week year_week
  FROM UNNEST([2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]) year, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, IF(EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE(1+year,1,1)) = 1, 52, 53))) week
), temp AS (
  SELECT i.run_id, w.year_week, d.year_week week2, value
  FROM  weeks w 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT run_id FROM `project.dataset.table`) i
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` d
  USING(year_week, run_id)
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT run_id, year_week, 
    SUM(value) OVER(win) aggregate_sum
  FROM temp
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY run_id ORDER BY year_week ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT row AND 4 FOLLOWING
  )
)
WHERE NOT aggregate_sum IS NULL
-- ORDER BY run_id, year_week
```

with result as

```
Row run_id  year_week   aggregate_sum    
1   001     201447      5    
2   001     201448      13   
3   001     201449      14   
4   001     201450      14   
5   001     201451      14   
6   001     201452      9    
7   001     201501      6    
8   001     201502      5        
9   001     201503      5    
10  001     201504      5    
11  001     201505      5
12  003     201348      8    
13  003     201349      9    
14  003     201350      9    
15  003     201351      9    
16  003     201352      9    
17  003     201401      6    
18  003     201402      5    
19  003     201403      5    
20  003     201404      5    
21  003     201405      5
```

note; this is for - `I only have 5 years, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 and 2017` but can easily be extended in weeks CTE

Comment: What is the elaboration of CTE?

Comment: CTE - common table expression - this is what you see after WITH abc AS (). so in CTE for weeks you can add as amny years as you need. Check more about [WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause)

Comment: Got it. Another question is why did you choose 3 as a date padding in ```select IF(EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE(1+year,1,3)) = 1, 52, 53)```? I suppose one could also choose something like ```select IF(EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE(1+year,1,1)) = 53, 53, 52)```. Why do you specifically go upto day 3 in your expression?

Comment: let me double check that `3` stuff - that sounds suspicious to me and can be just typo - will check and get back to you shortly with this

Comment: i checked - this is a typo - should be `1` - hard to say how this typo was introduced  - most likely when I tried to beautify the script before pasting to answer box. will update my answer. thank you for noticing :o)

Comment: If it is 1 then I think the  if function should be like this, `IF(EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE(1+year,1,1)) = 53, 53, 52)`

Comment: `... = 53, 53, 52)` and `... = 1, 52, 53)` will give you the same result :o) so you can use either. good catch. honestly - I am surprised you cannot apply same logic to you recent question :o( or I missed something there?

Comment: I just realized I can actually do the shifting even before doing the aggregation, just using the methods discussed here. Thanks!

Comment: exactly! glad you got it :o)

Comment: I think there is a problem in this answer, it is not working properly with different runs. The year_week that is not present in one run_id appears in another run_id.

Comment: sure. it is exactly the same as in another your post. fix will be the same. wait a little :o) but meantime, try to fix it by yourself - will be good exercise :o)

Comment: fixed - was missing `run_id` in `USING(year_week, run_id)` - try now!

Comment: That is perfect!

Comment: as always? :o)  see you in next posts